# Javascript toggle class not working as intended | No Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have the classname "active" to begin on the first sibling and switch to the next siblings after every 2 seconds. After the final sibling, it should come back to the first. Currently it adds the classname to every sibling, then begins to remove it from them sequentially at an interval of 2 seconds.

```
<body>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0;
        function toggle() {
            var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
            boxes[i].classList.toggle("active");
            i++;

            if (i >= boxes.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            
        }
        setInterval(toggle, 2000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the active class from the currently active element (if there is one) each time.

```
var i = 0;
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
function toggle() {
    document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
    boxes[i].classList.add("active");
    i = (i + 1) % boxes.length;
}
setInterval(toggle, 2000);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
function toggle() {
    document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
    boxes[i].classList.add("active");
    i = (i + 1) % boxes.length;
}
setInterval(toggle, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I have been trying for this since about a week. What a clever code. It checks active at the beginning of loop. 


By the way, could u please help me understand this line:

"i = (i + 1) % boxes.length;". The % part.

Comment: @RagingVids `%` takes the remainder after division, so when `i` is `boxes.length - 1` (the last element), `(i + 1) % boxes.length` will be `0`, which loops back to the start of the array.

Comment: Thanks a ton brother.

Comment: Im sorry I thought I did it. :D

Answer (score 1):

your toggle is doing something only on the current box. That doesn't affect the other siblings. In your code you need to 1) add class active on the current sibling 2) remove class active on the previous one :

```
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    function toggle() {
      var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    
      // add active class to the current box
      boxes[i].classList.add("active");

      // remove active class from the previous one
      if(i === 0) {
          boxes[boxes.length - 1].classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        boxes[i - 1].classList.remove("active");
      }
      
      i++;

      if (i >= boxes.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    setInterval(toggle, 2000);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This also works wonderfully well. Thank you so much. :)
But I wish to understand this part please: 

`if(i === 0) {
          boxes[boxes.length - 1].classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        boxes[i - 1].classList.remove("active");
      }`

I mean i===0 ?

Comment: When your first box is active, that means that your last box has probably the class active. So, in this case, you want to remove the class active from the last box, that means if your on box with the index 0, you want to remove the class from the box with the last index (boxes[boxes.length - 1]). In every other case you just pick the previous box, that means the i - 1 box.

Comment: Thank you so much.